# Output loop in php from a bacterium count per day

Tags: php, loops, for-loop

Here I have calculated the total number of bacterium present after 10 days of incubation. The user simply inputs the number of initial bacterium and is returned a result. What I am trying to do next has me somewhat confused. My goal now is to do this in a loop that also generates the output in a table on the web
page as shown below. x represents the total number of bacterium on that day number. Does anyone know how to execute this in php?

```
Initial Bacteria present:
Day: Bacteria:
1      x
.      x
.      x
.      x
10     x
```

Here is my php/html for the calculation.

```
<?php 
error_reporting(E_ALL);
ini_set('display_errors', 1);
?>  
<?php 
if(isset($_POST['submit'])) {
$x = (int)$_POST['initialBacteria'];
$days = 10;
$total = $x * pow(2, $days);
echo "There are: ", $total, " bacterium present in the culture after 10 days of incubation."; }     
//loop goes here
?>
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<link href="style/style.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />
</head>
<body>
<div align="center" id="main">
  <form action="<?php echo $_SERVER['PHP_SELF']; ?>" method="post" >
      Initial Bacterium:<input class="text" name="initialBacteria" type="text" size="15"><br><br>
      <input class="text" type="submit" name="submit" value="Calculate" />
  </form>      
<hr>
</div>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: What have you tried? If `$total = $x * pow(2, $days);` gives you the result for `$days` days how does the count change from day `n` to `n+1`?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can loop through the days and then insert the results into an array.

After inserting the data into an array, you can then use a `foreach` loop to echo out each result in the array.

```
<?php 
if(isset($_POST['submit'])) {
    $x = (int)$_POST['initialBacteria'];
    $days = 10;

    $total = array();
    for ($i=1; $i <= $days; $i++) { 
        $total[$i] = $x * pow(2, $i);
    }

    foreach ($total as $totalKey => $totalValue) {
        echo "There are: ", $totalValue, " bacterium present in the culture after ".$totalKey." days of incubation.<br />";
    }
}
 ?>
```

Here's my output when I entered `30` into `$x`'s value:
[image]

Comment: we're on the right track here. What I am getting now is Undefined index: initialBacteria in /home/user/public_html/index2.php on line 6

Comment: when i submit, the notice goes away, but I'd still like to know how to remove it.

Comment: oh i forgot to add the `if(isset($_POST['submit'])) {}` i'll edit my answer